# Visualisation of Web Data through API Calls

Tags: azure, rest, powerbi

i am using a Web server service where i am able to get real-time data using RestAPI calls. Now i want to be able to collect the data - store them somehow and then visualise them in a nice way (produce graphs basically). My approach would be to store them in a database and then use the PowerBI's internal feature "Get Data" from an "SQL Server Database". No idea if this the correct approach. Can anyone advise here ?

Comment: Once you start saving them in a database, it's not real time data anymore. But you may be interested to read [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

I agree with Andrey's comment above. But if you want to know about all the Data sources that PowerBI supports connecting to, please check the following resources:

- [Data sources in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources)
- [Power BI Data Source Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-source-prerequisites)
- [Connect to a web page from Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-to-web)
- [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming)

Additionally, you may also go through [Microsoft Power BI Guided Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guided-learning/) to understand the next steps for visualization.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach that is to build a custom data connector for that API to Power BI.
That allows you to fetch the data inside Power BI, and build the visuals. You can store it in excel files or sql (you can use python scripts for this) and you can schedule refreshes on the service.